# Make a 4d numpy array into a list of 3d numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(30, 100, 28, 28)` - 30 batches of 100 instances of 28x28. I would like to split this 4d numpy array into a list of length 30. In this list every element would be a numpy array of shape `(100, 28, 28)`. How can I do that?

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Did you try a list comprehension that simply iterates on the *4D* array? Your request is (at least) odd as the (*4D*) *NumPy* array offers the same interface (and more) as the resulting list.

Comment: `list(my_numpy_array)`

Answer (score 1):

First, you can already consider it as a list, without converting it at all, you can iterate through it or do everything you can do with a list.

But if you really want a list, all you have to do is to pass it in the list constructor :

```py
>>> m = np.zeros((30,100,28,28))
>>> m.shape
(30,100,28,28)
>>> l = list(m)
>>> type(l[0])
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> l[0].shape
(100, 28, 28)
>>> len(l)
30
```

l is your splitted list